# Check/match for IDs in two different tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have a SQLite DB with two tables and I want to merge/`FULL JOIN` these tables. [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/edfb1/1) for this question.

Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE cp_product(
  `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  `title` TEXT,
  `category_id` INTEGER,
  `locked` INTEGER
);
```

[image]

And table 2 which has those product IDs as foreign keys (brand_id):

```
CREATE TABLE cp_observation_strength_of_demands(
  `id` TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  `brand_id` INTEGER,
  `sold_level` INTEGER,
  `visit_id` TEXT,
  `status` INTEGER,
   FOREIGN KEY(brand_id) REFERENCES cp_product(id)
);
```

[image]

I am trying to merge both tables. I want to create new column say test and I want that column to store true if table 2 has brand_id from table 1 and false if otherwise. Like this:

[image]

Since SQLite does not support `FULL JOIN` I've created a query using `UNION ALL` but it returns all the IDs despite occurance in table 2 or not. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT A.*, B.* FROM cp_observation_strength_of_demands A LEFT JOIN cp_product B ON A.brand_id = B.id 
UNION ALL
SELECT A.*, B.* FROM cp_observation_strength_of_demands A LEFT JOIN cp_product B ON A.brand_id = B.id
WHERE B.category_id = 4 and A.sold_level = 1
```

Comment: It's a good idea to add table create query or at least a table in a text form. Images tend to die out. [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is also an option and will help others to answer your question.

Comment: Your example data does not have any `cp_observation_strength_of_demands` rows with no match in `cp_product`, so why do you need a full join instead of a right join?